# Clean update of QGIS LTR on Windows 10

Tags: qgis, update

I work in a company that uses QGIS on every computer. We chose to only install LTR versions as a precaution. So when the 3.4 version came out, we launched the installation on every computer. It was precisely the version 3.4.5.

This version crashes often (sometimes too much). We'd like to update to the current 3.4.11 that maybe helps with those bugs. But each update means a new QGIS program on our computer, it does not replace the old one.

I came here to ask what is the best way to upgrade between LTR version on Windows 10 ?

I saw two solutions that may answer my question, but I wanted to know if there's a better way (btw, I'm not the IT guy, so I can't test them myself):

1. OSGeo Network: can I use it to remove and reinstall a new version?
2. NextGIS: is it still up to date with QGIS 3+?

Should I use something else?

Comment: Don't you think this question might already be answered on the official QGIS-website?

Comment: @Erik Wish it was, I've looked, but they only recommend using OSGeo Network for the installation, nothing about replacing or updating LTR.

Comment: Always include such information in your question ;-) If I remember correctly, IT removed 3.4.5 before installing 3.4.9 on my computer, but that was mainly, because I asked them to do so. But they did so manually.

Comment: I think going from 3.4 to 3.8 for exemple install two QGIS on the computer (as they are two different QGIS version) but when going from 3.4,5 to 3.4.11 it ask you to uninstall 3.4.5 before installing 3.4.11 (as this is an update on the same version)

Comment: Thanks J.R, I need to try that, maybe that's the easiest solution.